# Modem Not Giving Internet to One Laptop, Giving Laptop to Another One

Tags: networking, modem

It's got me at a loss.  Here's my ipconfig:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::75ed:e280:7bcf:5ab8%20

   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.90.184

   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0

   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{F995A8D3-0E57-4658-9DD7-3D477E94C048}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

---

I WILL get Internet when I plug it into my Netgear router, but not directly to my modem.

Comment: You are not getting an IP address from DHCP, thus no connectivity. You could include more information about your "modem", but I will assume it is a cable modem. Most cable modems will only give out one IP address, and only to the first MAC address that is connected to it after it is powered on... cycling power on the modem would likely get you a valid IP address and internet connectivity. The proper way to connect this is to have everything behind the router, or get a business service package from your ISP with multiple static IP addresses.

Comment: @acejavelin the weird thing is when I power cycle modem, it gives me a default gateway for about 5 minutes, then it drops off.

Comment: Also, I work for the Internet company, so this modem is their business package.

Comment: Then I would suggest contacting your support desk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question fully but what I got was:

You have a laptop, which gets Internet connectivity if its connected to router via LAN cable or wifi, when the router is connected to the modem.

Your laptop doesn't get Internet connectivity when you connect it dorectly to the modem.

I would like to suggest checking your ISP's website.
log in to your account in ISP's website and check whether the MAC address of your laptop is registered or not. If it is not there then you should add it or contact ISP to do so.

And if you don't want to go through al this, then get your router's MAC address and change MAC address of your laptop.

Which you can see how [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-a-Computer's-Mac-Address-in-Windows).

Comment: My router's MAC, or my modem's MAC?

Comment: @ThomasHutton In order to get internet access from modem the client device's (router or laptop) MAC address should be recognized by the ISP, probably your router's MAC address is registered with the ISP and laptop's MAC is not. So, add laptop's MAC from ISP's website or change laptop's MAC (change it with router's MAC). Suppose your routers mac is A:B:C and laptop's MAC is D:E:F change laptop's MAC to A:B:C, because ISP provides internet to device which has A:B:C as their MAC which is registered with them (A:B:C is not the correct form of MAC I used it as example)

Comment: Thanks!  I was messing with a Netgear router awhile back and I accidentally spoofed the MAC address.  That was the issue.

Comment: Glad that this helped you, I deal with ISP regarding this sort of problems every week.